# MySQL query for string replacement and set String

Tags: mysql

I have string data in one cell and column type text.
    like example :

```
Q: {"newColumnName":"xxxx","filterList":[],"columnNames":"pqrs"}
```

columnNames,filterList,newColumnName  are not in fixed position may be change.
    i need to replace this above string data to

```
Need Result:{"columnNames":["pqrs"],"filterList":[],"parameters":{"newColumnName":"xxxx"}}
```

means i need to search and replace :-
1. "columnNames":"pqrs"------>"columnNames":["pqrs"].
2. "newColumnName":"xxxx" ------>"parameters":{"newColumnName":"xxxx"}.

pqrs and xxxx known to me. It can any string in there.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with a query like this:
It is ONLY a text replacement

to check

```
SELECT t.val
        , REPLACE(
            REPLACE(t.val,'"columnNames":"pqrs"','"columnNames":["pqrs"]')
            , '"newColumnName":"xxxx"' , '"parameters":{"newColumnName":"xxxx"}') as result
FROM tt t;
```

to replace

```
UPDATE tt
    set tt.val =
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(tt.val,'"columnNames":"pqrs"','"columnNames":["pqrs"]')
            , '"newColumnName":"xxxx"' , '"parameters":{"newColumnName":"xxxx"}');
```

Comment: if string xxxx and pqrs is not fixed or unknown to me then how to handle replace query.

Comment: which MySQL Version you are using: **SELECT VERSION();**

Comment: my version is 5.7.22

Comment: Iam not at home. I give you the answer later

Comment: Ok, When you will back